# AWS EMR Spark: Error: Cannot load main class from JAR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to submit a spark job to AWS EMR cluster using AWS console. But it fails with:

`Cannot load main class from JAR`. The job runs successfully when I specify main class as `--class` in `Arguments` option in AWS EMR Console-> Add Step.

On the local machine, the job seems to work perfectly fine when no main class is specified as below:

```
 ./spark-submit /home/astro/spark-programs/SpotEMR/MyJob.jar
```

I have set main class to jar using run configuration. The main reason to avoid passing main class as `--class` is, I have to run this job in AWS Datapipeline using EMRAcivity. In AWS Datapipeline, currently there is no way to specify a main class to a job being submitted.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @Frederic: Do you have any doc that confirms this thing?

Comment: please see my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you *can* pass the job's main class with EMRActivity and AWS Datapipeline.

See
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-object-emractivity.html to launch a `EMRActivity` using `step`.

as well as
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-submit-step.html to submit a spark job using an EMR `step` with a main class.

The step would look as follows:

```
command-runner.jar,spark-submit,--class,org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: I did try the way you mentioned here. Its still failing. Will check logs for the possible cause

Comment: No AMI required. Works with the current EMR release.

Comment: When I try this it gives me EmrCluster is supported only for AmiVersion 2.4.8 and above for hadoop 1 and AmiVersion 3.1.1 and above for hadoop 2. You are using AmiVersion 2.3.0'

When I tried to run it on 4.3 version and 5.11, it goes in canceled state with no errors

Comment: do you have any doc that explains the steps required to run emr job on amazon datapipeline?

Comment: https://github.com/awslabs/data-pipeline-samples/blob/master/samples/SparkPiMaximizeResourceAllocation/SparkPi-maximizeResource.json or use "Build using a template"