# How to create EMR cluster on demand and execute aws emr command?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, emr, amazon-emr

I want to execute Spark jobs on demand. So, only when I receive a trigger event, I want to execute a Spark job, using the inputs arriving with this trigger event. Since trigger events are not frequent, I do not want to use Spark Streaming.
My goal is to deploy the tool in AWS EMR cluster. I want to be able to create EMR cluster on demand (by triggers), execute Spark job there and switch off a cluster.
Is there any good example of how to handle these operations from Scala?

Comment: it depends, what kind of event would be the trigger ? Your question is too vague, but in general, more than a language, to perform actions on events you need some kind of message queue. For instance you can use a mix of AWS CloudWatch (for the events) and 
AWS Data Pipeline  (for the spark job)

Comment: Manually setup EMR via the Amazon console. Measure how long it takes for the cluster to go online. Then do the same from the AWS CLI. You will find that EMR setup takes a while (more than a few minutes). Also pay attention the minimum bill rate for launching a cluster. EMR is not a quick start and stop on demand type service in comparison to Lambda, EC2, etc. Don't use CloudWatch for launching EMR. You might wind up with lots of expensive clusters in the cloud.

Comment: @RobertoCongiu: Triggers (events) will come through RabbitMQ. I receive them and process them in Scala. But my question is how to run launch `aws emr` command from Scala in order to create a cluster and run Spark job?

Comment: @JohnHanley: The closest implementation to what I need is to use `AmazonElasticMapReduceClient`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-submit-step.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [AWS Data Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/) seems to be a right solution for the problem you defined. AWS Data Pipeline allows you to connect multiple ranges of services within your AWS infrastructures such as storage and processing.
- You can create a EMR job using an EMRActivity in AWS Data pipeline. The pipeline will trigger when it meets a pre-condition or at a scheduled interval.
- It will set up an EMR cluster with the specification you specified and the Spark step you defined
- The cluster can be terminated automatically when the job is completed.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407769/aws-emr-spark-error-cannot-load-main-class-from-jar?noredirect=1#comment83837510_48407769) on SO will get you started.

- You can also spin up an AWS Data Pipeline [using this definition](https://github.com/aws-samples/data-pipeline-samples/blob/master/samples/SparkPiMaximizeResourceAllocation/SparkPi-maximizeResource.json) while creating a pipeline using `Choose a Template` option. For this option, you can use the template shared above.

Answer (score 1):

A Lambda function could be a good solution as long at it allows to start EMR clusters. A Lambda function can be started on demand or using a number of different triggers to be invoked.

This could be a good template to start setting up your Lambda function:

`

```
import sys
import time

import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    conn = boto3.client("emr")
    # chooses the first cluster which is Running or Waiting
    # possibly can also choose by name or already have the cluster id
    clusters = conn.list_clusters()
    # choose the correct cluster
    clusters = [c["Id"] for c in clusters["Clusters"] 
                if c["Status"]["State"] in ["RUNNING", "WAITING"]]
    if not clusters:
        sys.stderr.write("No valid clusters\n")
        sys.stderr.exit()
    # take the first relevant cluster
    cluster_id = clusters[0]
    # code location on your emr master node
    CODE_DIR = "/home/hadoop/code/"

    # spark configuration example
    step_args = ["/usr/bin/spark-submit", "--spark-conf", "your-configuration",
                 CODE_DIR + "your_file.py", '--your-parameters', 'parameters']

    step = {"Name": "what_you_do-" + time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H:%M"),
            'ActionOnFailure': 'CONTINUE',
            'HadoopJarStep': {
                'Jar': 's3n://elasticmapreduce/libs/script-runner/script-runner.jar',
                'Args': step_args
            }
        }
    action = conn.add_job_flow_steps(JobFlowId=cluster_id, Steps=[step])
    return "Added step: %s"%(action)
```

`

Answer (score 0):

1. instead of spinning EMR cluster via api its better to have EMR
   configured in cloud formation template and start the cloud formation
   template (CFT). by CFT u can handle IAM roles, creation of S3
   buckets etc
2. Spin the EMR cluster via lambda; and have another lambda monitor the EMR if there is any spark job in progress or waiting. if there is none for an *idle time (say 15min)*, then issue a tear down on the CFT which inturn terminates the EMR